# Is it possible to Inject a CSS Framework for a Module and all its components in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, styles, angular-module, angular2-styleguide

I'm Developing an application that contains 2 Modules, **one** module for **admin** layout and **another** module for **user** layout. I'm planning to use 2 different frameworks. one for admin and another for user.

one framework that affects the other so i cant keep both in .angular-cli.json globally. So Is there any possibilities to use a framework for one module and another for another. without affecting the styles.

Comment: Don't add css globally.
Add css for each component

Answer (score 0):

In user.component.css (top level component for user.module):

```
@import 'my-first-framework';
```

In admin.component.css (top level component for admin.module):

```
@import 'my-second-framework';
```

In admin.component.ts, user.component.ts (top level components for modules)

```
@Component({
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none
})
```

Comment: what about the scripts ?

Comment: check out [angular-cli stories - global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)